# How could I properly pause/resume considering the rebalancing that occurs as I add a new consumer for a long running processing?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm using Kafka 2.3.1 (server) with spring-kafka 2.2.14 and kafka-clients 2.0.1.

I have a topic with 10 partitions.

**Producer**

One producer publishes messages to the Kafka cluster, distributing them among partitions according to the key, as the order by key of messages matters.

```
acks = all
```

**Consumer**

Some instances of the same consumer (starting from 2 to 5 with horizontal scaling in k8s), each with only one thread, pull these messages and perform processing.

Message processing time varies unpredictably.

Trying to avoid frequently group rebalancing, I moved message processing to another thread. The consumer continues calling poll while the processor is still working.

```
auto.offset.reset = earliest
enable.auto.commit = false
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 1
AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE    
syncCommits = true
```

**Execution example**

10 partitions were assigned to consumer-0 (0 to 4) and consumer-1 (5 to 9). New consumers are added during processing, and each addition causes rebalancing. I cannot resume partitions that were paused before.

message-1 was consumed twice. Since processing takes longer than `max.poll.interval.ms`, rebalancing rearranges partitions. When the commit is triggered, it is possible that the offset partition is associated with another consumer. And this commit takes effect. The rebalancing is probably resuming all paused partitions. The new consumer associated with this partition is able to pull the message again because it is not paused.

```
consumer-1 [partition-5 offset-12] Received Message [message-1]
consumer-1 [partition-5 offset-12] Paused Partitions [partition-5, partition-8, partition-9, partition-6, partition-7]
consumer-2 Started
consumer-2 [partition-3 offset-80] Received Message [message-2]
consumer-2 [partition-3 offset-80] Paused Partitions [partition-2, partition-3, partition-0, partition-1]
consumer-3 Started
consumer-3 [partition-7 offset-43] Received Message [message-3]
consumer-3 [partition-7 offset-43] Paused Partitions [partition-6, partition-7]
consumer-4 Started
consumer-4 [partition-5 offset-12] Received Message [message-1]
consumer-4 [partition-5 offset-12] Paused Partitions [partition-4, partition-5]
consumer-1 [partition-5 offset-12] Executed Task 
consumer-1 [partition-5 offset-12] Committed [message-1]
consumer-1 [partition-5 offset-12] Resumed Partitions []
consumer-2 [partition-3 offset-80] Executed Task
consumer-2 [partition-3 offset-80] Committed [message-2]
consumer-2 [partition-3 offset-80] Resumed Partitions []
consumer-3 [partition-7 offset-43] Executed Task
consumer-3 [partition-7 offset-43] Committed [message-3]
consumer-3 [partition-7 offset-43] Resumed Partitions []
consumer-4 [partition-5 offset-12] Executed Task
consumer-4 [partition-5 offset-12] Committed [message-1]
consumer-4 [partition-5 offset-12] Resumed Partitions [partition-4, partition-5]
```

**Consumer implementation in Groovy**

```java
    @KafkaListener(topics = '${topic.files}', 
                   containerFactory = "fileKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    void receive(@Payload FileEvent event,
                 @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
                 @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offset,
                 Acknowledgment ack,
                 Consumer consumer) {
        LOGGER.info("[partition-{} offset-{}] Received Message [{}]", partition, offset, event)
        try {
            LOGGER.debug("[partition-{} offset-{}] Paused Partitions [{}]", partition, offset, consumer.assignment())
            consumer.pause(consumer.assignment())
            ListenableFuture<Void> future = applicationTaskExecutor.submitListenable(callable(event))
            future.addCallback({ }, { ex -> throw ex }  )
            while (!future.isDone()) {
                Thread.sleep(500)
                consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(3_000))
            }
            future.get()
            ack.acknowledge()
            LOGGER.debug("[partition-{} offset-{}] Committed [{}]", partition, offset, event)
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            String message = String.format("Fail to consume partition=%s offset=%s %s", partition, offset, event)
            throw new RuntimeException(message, cause)
        } finally {
            LOGGER.debug("[partition-{} offset-{}] Resumed Partitions [{}]", partition, offset, consumer.paused())
            consumer.resume(consumer.paused())
        }
    }
    
    Callable<Void> callable(FileEvent event) {
        { ->
            indexService.index(event)
        }
    }
```

How could I properly pause/resume considering the rebalancing that occurs as I add a new consumer for a long running processing?

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `pause()` / `resume()` on the consumer itself; pause the listener container instead (and set `max.poll.records` to 1).

The container has logic to re-pause after a rebalance.

```java
if (ListenerConsumer.this.consumerPaused) {
    ListenerConsumer.this.consumer.pause(partitions);
    ListenerConsumer.this.logger.warn("Paused consumer resumed by Kafka due to rebalance; "
            + "consumer paused again, so the initial poll() will never return any records");
}
```

If you really want to do all this yourself, set `max.poll.records` to 1 and use a rebalance listener to re-pause the consumer.

Comment: I set an `id` in `@KafkaListener`, paused the listener container using `registry.getListenerContainer(<id-value>).pause()` and continued calling `consumer.poll()` in a loop while processing. This works, but after calling `registry.getListenerContainer(<id-value>).resume()`, no messages were consumed, even I called `consumer.poll()` again after the resume. Could you show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's a lot simpler to let the container manage all this for you rather than interacting with the consumer itself; if you don't release the listener thread, the container can't react to the pause/resume request. It's easier if you let the container manage all this and don't interact with the consumer itself. Pause the container, hand the work off to another thread; use the idleEventInterval and an event listener to resume the container when the current work is done. As I said, if you write the code yourself, you will need to add a rebalance listener to re-pause the consumer.

Comment: What you are trying to do simply won't work - if a rebalance occurs while you are in your `poll()` loop, you can lose the partition you are currently working on. The rebalance listener is called from your `poll()` call. It's generally better to increase the `max.poll.interval` rather than attempting to "resolve" the problem with these pause/resume dances. As you have found, pause/resume is only useful with a stable environment (no rebalancing).